# InDesign CS6 Check the XML document for specific attribute

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an xml file with the attribute style inside the resultset

```
<resultset statement="select adtext  from ad where adCategoryID=3 order by adinsertdate desc limit 100" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" style="cars">
```

The value of the attribute may vary in different xml files, so I would like to get the value of the attribute and apply the corresponding styling to my xml, according to this value.

However no matter what variations I try in this statement:

```
if(myTemplate.XMLElement.XMLAttributes.itemByName("style").value == "cars"){//...}
```

I get the following message:

**"Object does not support the property or method 'XMLElement'.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take care to **not** mix up the [Class name](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XMLElement.html) and the [property name](jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XMLElement.html#xmlElements).

Comment: So I need to create an XMLElement Object to access the attribute XMLAttributes.Obviously myTemplate is not of that kind of Object though... So I need an XMLElement Object that is found inside myTemplate (which is my document), right?

Comment: Wrong. You cannot "create" these objects as a variable as you would in an actual programming language, you can only *access* existing ones. So use `myTemplate.xmlElements(some_ref_here).xmlAttributes` -- etc. (where `some_ref_here` needs to point to an existing XML element).

Comment: So in my case where I import the xml file in myTemplate.indt, what will be my "some_ref_here"? I'm a newbie to InDesign so I can' really figure this out.